# how to make a textBox change its height when the number of lines change

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

i made usercontrol with two textboxses. one of them is multiline and other textbox is single line which stays at bottom of multiline textbox. i want to change multiline textbox's height based on number of lines of content and stick single line textbox to this multiline textbox visually(no spacing between two textboxes).

Comment: Do you plan to stop this growth at some size or it is infinite?

Comment: So, where is your problem? Use the TextChanged event and the Lines.Count property..

Comment: it should be infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SizeF size;
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics G = textBox1.CreateGraphics())
        size = G.MeasureString("Xy_", textBox1.Font, 999);

    textBox1.Height = (int)(textBox1.Lines.Count() * size.Height + 5);
    textBox2.Top = textBox1.Bottom - 1;
}
```

The using line really could and should be moved to the Form constructor.. Depending on your font and Borders you want to adapt the two correction numbers..

Comment: i have another question, how do i make usercontrol1 form scale with those two textboxes? even there is a 1 line text usercontrol1 height makes a space below

Comment: That would depend on how much space you want above and below. With no space below you could write: `uc1.Height = textBox1.Top + textBoxt1.Height + textBox.Height;`